# Mass updating .net web applications

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, deployment

So I have a .net web application that I use the VS 2010 "publish" feature to deploy to a server.  Each instance of the application has its own unique connection string, pointing to its own database.

I have 80 instances of this application.  I would like to be able to update 1 instance with a "master" version of the app, and then have the other 79 update themselves, but keep their existing connection string.

What is the most common / standard way of achieving this?

Comment: Simple xcopy or powershell script should be able to do this.

Comment: @amit_g I do not think that xcopy is so powerful.

Comment: Should have been more clear - xcopy from a dos batch.

Comment: Wouldnt xcopy write over the web.config?

Comment: You can use the /EXCLUDE option in xcopy to exclude certain files.

Comment: See if http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the properties of the web.config file (solution explorer) you can set the "Build Action" to "none".

Then deploy the webapp to a local directory. This is now without that web.config file.

Then copy that local directory over your 80 applications. You could maybe automate this step.

Comment: So there aren't any tools designed for this scenario?  I figured it would be a pretty common scenario.  Red-gate has a tool like this for SQL Server (SQL Compare).  I was hoping there'd be a product focussed on this - or a tool from MS

Comment: I think this is probably the simplest approach.  This combined with the xcopy suggestion above

Answer (score 0):

There are simple deployment tools that can take care of coping binary packages over multiple servers while maintaining a customized configuration. KwateeSDCM is a free tool that can do this. You can look it up on freshmeat

(I don't seem to able to respond to your comment so I edited my answer)
Ken - yeah, the doc is really slim. They've got a video tutorial that is actually a lot more useful and I also got some pointers from one of their developers. Honestly, I don't know that much about asp.net but from what you describe it looks very similar to what I setup with my tomcat web applications (war) on my 30 servers. You define a "package" which is simply a zipped (or tared) archive of the files/executables you have to deploy, configure the target servers and then tell sdcm which package goes on which server. There's a sort of environment variable concept which you can use in your configuration files (in your case, %{connection_string}) has placeholders which get substituted at installation-time with the server-specific values that you specify in your sdcm configuration. With about half a day's work I manage to configure kwateesdcm so that with a single click it connects to each server, stops tomcat, copies over my archives, expands them where I need to, substitutes the server-specific parameters and restarts tomcat to take all changes into account. The cool thing is that sdcm also archives previous archives/configurations so that it's which takes a lot of stress out of updates since I can quickly revert to a previous stable version if my latest stuff had problems. One annoying thing is that it requires an ssh server on each target server. I got over that by installing winsshd on my servers

Comment: Hi Macolm - so I checked out KwateeSDCM's website, but I couldn't see anything about asp.net, and the documentation was pretty slim.  Have you used this with asp.net applications?